# mysql to check room is exists for a particular date with time duration

Tags: mysql, sql

I have check room is exists between two time for particular date.

[image: MY TABLE LIKE THIS]

I have try following two query its run some time rights but, when i select 10:00 AM to 12:00 PM at time wrong results means not return any records.

**QUERY-1** :

```
SELECT 1 FROM `timetable_details` WHERE (
        ((`td_from` <= '10:00:00') AND (`td_to` > '10:00:00')) 
        OR 
        ((`td_from` < '12:20:00') AND (`td_to` >= '12:20:00'))

    ) AND ((`td_room`='1') AND (`td_date`='2016-01-25'))
```

**QUERY-2** :

```
SELECT 1 FROM `timetable_details` WHERE (
            (`td_from` > '07:00:00') AND (`td_to` < '08:00:00')
      ) AND ((`td_room`='1') AND (`td_date`='2016-01-25'))
```

I have get `td_id = 4` number row but is not returns.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQlite or? Don't tag products not involved...

Comment: @jarlh Ok, sir I remove tag , I used `MySQL`

Comment: The td_from and td_to, are they declared as datetime?

Comment: @Trevor no td_from and td_to is `time`

Comment: What result do you get - what do you expect to get ?

Comment: As it seems, no record meets the condition , therefore , no rows should be returned. What is the output now? and what is the output that you want?

Comment: I have check room is exists in two time duration like `10:00 AM to 12:00 AM`  with particular date with room id. In Query-1 `10:00:00` is start time and 12:20:00 is end time

Comment: but all the data you gave us one been one hour , so how would you expect to get results?

Comment: I have check room is allocated in between two time. My query-1 is working some time but my above scenario is not working

Comment: Listen - update your question and add desired output and current output becuase i just cant understand you.

Comment: @sagi I have only check record is exists please view my Query-1 and my scenario is, When i have enter start time = 10:00:00 and end time = 12:00:00 at time return results is null but `td_id = 4 ` in above image is allocated in 2016-01-25. i have select this records but not available in my query results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100353/discussion-between-hiren-bhut-and-sagi).

Comment: @hirenBhut, you can please check data type for date field as well as time field.

Comment: I think your condition is wrong. As in condition you are checking ((`td_from` <= '10:00:00') AND (`td_to` > '10:00:00'))  which means time should be greater than 10 am but less than or equals to 10 am also. This condition is never going to meet. That's why you are not getting any rows. I think as @Karmraj Zala suggested use between keyword.

Comment: @MohitAggarwal I try @Karmraj Zala query but is not satisfied when start time and end time is equal like 10:00 to 11:00 at time 11:00 is td_from time in `td = 4` id at time return results but i have not return any record. this situation. (In short start time and end time is not equal)

Comment: I think you need to tell what is your expected output then only we can help you with right sql query

Comment: @HirenBhut. Please check my updated answer. Now you will get perfect result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `between` with `OR condition` for both columns as below :

```
SELECT 1 FROM `timetable_details` WHERE (((((`td_from` BETWEEN '10:00:00' AND '12:30:00') OR (`td_to` BETWEEN '10:00:00' AND '12:30:00')) AND ((`td_room`='1') AND (`td_date`='2016-01-25') AND (`td_status` IS NULL))) AND (`td_from` <> '12:30:00')) AND (`td_to` <> '10:00:00'))
```